# Grid Hide/Show animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers, grid

I've got some User Control, which is grid with transparent background, on top of that there's another grid that is suppose to change its width when triggers are fired (ultimately it'll be a in/out animation). Purpose was to simply use something different than Visibility that was instantly hiding entire control without any animations Here's the property it's based on:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register ("IsOpened", typeof (Boolean), typeof (SidePanel), new PropertyMetadata (false));

    public bool IsOpened {
        get {
            if (GetValue (IsOpenedProperty) != null)
                return (bool)GetValue (IsOpenedProperty);
            else
                return false;
        }
        set {
            SetValue (IsOpenedProperty, value);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
```

And the Grid itself:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOpened}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="350"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOpened}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Side, Path=Width}"/>
</Grid>
```

Console gives me corect output but triggers don't fire at all.

Just checked one more thing and when I set trigger for x:Null value then it's fired all the time, how is it possible as Get shouldn't ever return null value here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I just gave up on dependency property here, created private variable to hold the value and added data context with INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation and now it works.